# alloc init vs Convenience initializer for strong property

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

So in one of my Objective C classes I have a strong property say:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray     *tags;
```

Which of the following is a better way to initialise this property

1 `self.tags = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`

or

2 `self.tags = [NSMutableArray array];`

Answer (score 3):

With ARC, there is *almost* no difference. `[NSMutableArray array]` returns an ["unretained
return value"](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#unretained-return-values) which might have been put into the autorelease pool (and that actually happens
in your example, which you can see by inspecting the generated Assembler code).

This additional reference is released later, when the current autorelease pool ends.
So there is a slight overhead in the second method.

On the other hand, the Objective-C *runtime* has various methods to avoid unnecessary
retain/release calls (e.g. by inspecting the call stack), so the difference might be negligible.

Comment: NSObject's memory-management elision powers are still in their infancy.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your definition of better. First, if you are in the `init` method, you should not use `self.tags =` for the assignment at all, as you should not call methods from the `init` methods. Instead, access the instance variable directly:

```
_tags = ...;
```

As for the possible ways of doing it:

```
_tags = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

is currently a bit faster than

```
_tags = [NSMutableArray array];
```

but is also longer. And we should never optimize for a performance problem we haven't measured. If you are going for readability and short code, I would suggest a third option:

```
_tags = [NSMutableArray new];
```

In fact you can have even shorter code, but it may make your eyes bleed:

```
_tags = [@[] mutableCopy];
```

Extra track: Early in ARC the default for object properties has been `assign`, but it changed to `strong` pretty fast. So instead of

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *tags;
```

you can just use

```
@property(nonatomic) NSMutableArray *tags;
```